# CSS selector for expanded select (dropdown) element

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I style a drop down different when it is open or closed? Is there any pseudo selectors or tricks for that? 
of course with out javascript.

```
<select>
  <option> op1 </option>
  <option> op2 </option>
</select>
```

and :hover doesn't really suit my need because when the drop down is expanded, i can move the cursor away. it still is open but the :hover styling doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Comment: @Wavemaster i'm not asking for the styling of a dropdown (select) in general but only if there is a selector for the "open state"!

Comment: Then the answer is simple: **no**. Without JavaScript, there is no "open state" selector. And I'm not sure if there's a way with js.

Answer (score -3):

Are you looking for `:hover`?

It's the state of an element if the mouse is over it.

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: overline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Move the mouse over me</a>
```

Comment: No. when it is expanded. e.g. i have <select> <option>something</option></select> when i click on a drop down it expands then i can move my cursor away and it still is expanded. and i would like the styling still be there. then when i click again and it collapses, then the styling should be reversed again.

Comment: You should write that in your question. Also you should provide the code you have already tried.